# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder

Tags: json, scala, logging, sbt, slf4j

I am new to Scala and I am trying to generate logs in json format for an existing sbt project, but i am getting the error below -

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder

I have added these dependencies to the build.sbt

```
  "net.logstash.logback"  % "logstash-logback-encoder" % "4.11",
  "ch.qos.logback"        % "logback-core"             % "1.2.3",
  "ch.qos.logback"        % "logback-access"           % "1.2.3"
```

and my logback.xml looks like this -

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>app.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <!--<encoder>
            <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd} %X{akkaTimestamp} %-5level[%thread] %logger{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>-->
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

> Scala Version 2.12.3
>   SBT Version 1.0.3

Where I might be going wrong, any help will be appreciated .

Comment: You should check if this class for encoder exists in the classpath of your app.

Comment: Did you fix it? What was the problem?

Comment: It "should" be in that logstash-logback-encoder jar, double check it made it...

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem in Jenkins. But I was not doing the logging in json format. I used `akka-http`, which had `SLF4J/logback` for logging.

And this `logback.xml` fixed my problem:

```
<configuration>
     <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
         <target>System.out</target>
         <encoder>
             <pattern>%X{akkaTimestamp} %-5level[%thread] %logger{0} - %msg%n</pattern>
         </encoder>
     </appender>

     <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
         <file>akka.log</file>
         <append>true</append>
         <encoder>
             <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd} %X{akkaTimestamp} %-5level[%thread] %logger{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
         </encoder>
     </appender>

     <logger name="akka" level="DEBUG"/>

     <root level="DEBUG">
         <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
         <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
     </root>
 </configuration>
```

Not sure will it fix your problem or not. Would love to know more details about the problem.